# Add Label to OneLineAvataListItem Python kivy

Tags: python, kivy

My problem: When i try to add label for each OneLineAvatarListItem widget, label added to last widget
I just want customize ListItem his font_name, but OneLineAvatarListItem widget don't have this argument

```
`from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, ThreeLineListItem, OneLineAvatarListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import ImageLeftWidget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        scroll = ScrollView()
        list_view = MDList()
        scroll.add_widget(list_view)
        data = ['dog', 'cat']
        for i in data:
            lbl =  Label(text=i, font_name='bebas-neue-bold', color=[.1, .1, .1, 1])
            items = OneLineAvatarListItem(text=i)
            items.add_widget(lbl)
            list_view.add_widget(items)
        screen.add_widget(scroll)
        return screen
            
        

    
DemoApp().run()`
```

Comment: it seems it can't add other items. And `OneLineAvatarListItem` has `font_style`  like `H1` which you can see in `self.theme_cls.font_styles` and you can add own style `self.theme_cls.font_styles['MyStyle'] = ["RobotoLight", 40, False, -1.5]` and `OneLineAvatarListItem(..., font_style="MyStyle")`. But it may need also other changes to load your font.

Comment: source code [font_styles](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/theming.py#L934) and [fonts](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/font_definitions.py#L14)

Answer (score 0):

`OneLineAvatarListItem` has `font_style` which use predefineds [styles](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/theming.py#L934) and predefined [fonts](https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/blob/master/kivymd/font_definitions.py#L14).

Digging in source code I font method to add own font (on Linux Mint)

```
from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

#from kivymd import fonts_path
#print('fonts_path:', fonts_path)

my_font_path = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/'

font = {
        "name": "Ubuntu",
        "fn_regular":    my_font_path + "Ubuntu-R.ttf",
        "fn_bold":       my_font_path + "Ubuntu-B.ttf",
        "fn_italic":     my_font_path + "Ubuntu-RI.ttf",
        "fn_bolditalic": my_font_path + "Ubuntu-BI.ttf",
}

LabelBase.register(**font)
```

And later I can create own style

```
    def build(self):

        self.theme_cls.font_styles['MyStyle'] = ["Ubuntu", 40, False, -1.5]
        # [font_name, font_size, upper_case, ???]
```

and then I can use it

```
    items = OneLineAvatarListItem(text=i, font_style='MyStyle')
```

---

Full working example for Linux Mint

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, ThreeLineListItem, OneLineAvatarListItem
from kivymd.uix.list import ImageLeftWidget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.core.text import LabelBase

#from kivymd import fonts_path
#print('fonts_path:', fonts_path)

my_font_path = '/usr/share/fonts/truetype/ubuntu/'

font = {
        "name": "Ubuntu",
        "fn_regular":    my_font_path + "Ubuntu-R.ttf",
        "fn_bold":       my_font_path + "Ubuntu-B.ttf",
        "fn_italic":     my_font_path + "Ubuntu-RI.ttf",
        "fn_bolditalic": my_font_path + "Ubuntu-BI.ttf",
}

LabelBase.register(**font)

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        scroll = ScrollView()

        # [font_name, font_size, upper_case, ???]
        self.theme_cls.font_styles['MyStyle'] = ["Ubuntu", 40, False, -1.5]
        
        list_view = MDList()
        scroll.add_widget(list_view)

        data = ['dog', 'cat', 'cow']
        for i in data:

            # `text_color` works only if `theme_text_color='Custom'`
            items = OneLineAvatarListItem(text=i, font_style='MyStyle', text_color=[1, 0, 0, 1], theme_text_color='Custom')

            list_view.add_widget(items)

        screen.add_widget(scroll)
        
        return screen
    
DemoApp().run()
```

Comment: ValueError: OneLineAvatarListItem.font_style is set to an invalid option 'MyStyle'. Must be one of: ['H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'Subtitle1', 'Subtitle2', 'Body1', 'Body2', 'Button', 'Caption', 'Overline', 'Icon'] im get this error

Comment: did you use `self.theme_cls.font_styles['MyStyle'] = ["Ubuntu", 40, False, -1.5]` from my example?

Comment: yes, im used, i think font not be added to font_style's

Comment: You may try `print( self.theme_cls.font_styles )` after adding `MyStyle` and directly before `OneLineAvatarListItem`. Maybe it is in wrong place. OR you will have to create new question on new page and you will have more space to put full code with description.